# Mercurial: Pull from official repo, push to man-in-the-middle repo?

Tags: mercurial

I have a situation where on a dev server I'd like to pull from the official repo. I'd make my changes there, then I'd like to push to a core server, test there as well, then from that core server I'd like to pull from dev (preferably automatically accept the push from dev) and push to the official repo. I need some help setting up this trifecta.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I solved it by using the following format:
on dev I added this line to my hgrc file:

```
default-push = ssh://name@core/project/
```

and I setup passwordless ssh between the machines. I then was able to pull from official on dev, push to core on dev, and then from core just type hg update to get the changes. On core I can then push to official.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What problems are you having?  This seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: I don't know how to change where one repo pulls from and pushes to, or make one repo automatically accept pushes from a location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup default paths for push and pull in your `hgrc` file.  See the [documentation for `[paths]` in the `hgrc`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths).

You can also setup "named" remote repositories by doing something like this:

`[paths]`
`dev = http://path/to/dev/repo`

Then you can run `hg push dev` to push to that URL.

Comment: I'm confused with the http part though. I want to push from one folder on dev to another folder on core... they aren't "webservers" though

Comment: @Faramir: The path does not need to be a URL.  It could be a relational or absolute path as well (for example `../dev` or `/home/user/dev`.